# Why a daily vote cap on a new beta site?

Tags: discussion, beta, voting

As I've been voting on stuff posted in the beta ([early and often](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often)), I'm getting a message about nearing my daily vote limit. When we're intentionally trying to seed the site with content, we shouldn't restrict the number of votes that early users are allowed to cast.

Comment: Should be asked on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Maybe we can do vote trading!  I'm really bad at voting so I'll sell some of my votes ...

Answer (score 3):

Completely agree! I see no reason for a vote limit, and even if there is one, 30 votes per day seems too restrictive.

Answer (score 3):

I actually like the vote cap, even now in private beta. It gives me something concrete to aim for, but also tells me it's time to go do some maths again. That said, I second the suggestion to ask this on meta.stackoverflow.com.